# How can a Chat-Enabled Notebook be set up to automatically use Wolfram Language Evaluator?

Tags: notebooks, user-interface, chatai, version-13.3

In the release [blog post](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) for `v13.3` Stephen Wolfram gives the following example for a Chat-Enabled Notebook.

[image: Wolfram Blog]

As it appears there is automatic evaluation, e.g., `Used Wolfram Language Evaluator`. Working in a new Chat-Enabled Notebook, my attempt to replicate that nice example is not as impressive, e.g., there is no automatic use of an evaluator—instead we need to explicitly call an evaluator using an icon that will pop up when we click on the inside window showing Wolfram Language code.

[image: Replication]

While the code works out correctly (giving a slightly different plot), I wonder how automatic evaluation as shown in the blog can be achieved in `v13.3`?

EDIT

While it is certainly true that we would need to “sandbox” the evaluator to prevent damages to our system as commentators rightly pointed out, one would likely want to have the same user experience as someone using OpenAI’s web interface with the Wolfram PlugIn. The blog post is essentially “selling” that use case implicitly.

NOTE: I crossposted this as an issue in the GitHub repository `WolramResearch/Chatbook` ([here](https://github.com/WolframResearch/Chatbook/issues/220)).

Comment: I have the same question. Possibly the default is to allow the user to inspect the code before evaluation for performance and/or security reasons.

Comment: Suppose the generated code is to delete your files......

Comment: @Lacia Good point, but then I would have asked, “FBI is coming,  what can I do?”:D

Comment: @gwr It seems that the evaluation is done by ``Wolfram`Chatbook`Tools`$defaultChatTools["wolfram_language_evaluator"] `` which points to the function ``Wolfram`Chatbook`Tools`Private`sandboxEvaluate ``. But I have no idea how to automate it.

Comment: @gwr Maybe you can open an issue here https://github.com/WolframResearch/Chatbook/issues

Comment: I may be completely missing the point, but can't you set the default via Preferences/AI Settings? The list selector allows you to set the default to be any of the installed LLM evaluators - 6 of them on my machine.

Comment: @jdp Well, which of those will give you a result similar to the one Stephen Wolfram has posted?

Comment: Sorry, I got "LLM evaluator" confused with "Wolfram Language Evaluator". I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will relay Rick Hennigan's answer given on [GitHub](https://github.com/WolframResearch/Chatbook/issues/220#issuecomment-1618878150).

> The tools are currently only enabled by default for GPT-4, since
> GPT-3.5 almost always fails to use them correctly. If you have access
> to GPT-4 with your API key, you should be able to see outputs like
> these when using that model. Note that for that particular example,
> GPT-4 makes a call to the WL evaluator approximately 60% of the time,
> so it's not guaranteed that you'll see similar results.

> If you want to force GPT-3.5 to use tools, you can enable it via the "ToolsEnabled" option when creating the notebook:

```
CreateNotebook["ChatEnabled", "ToolsEnabled" -> True]
```

> However, GPT-3.5 simply does not understand the tool-calling instructions, so you will not get useful results.

Comment: Too bad, but currently I only have access to the `GPT-3.5` API. Currently, OpenAI's web interface is more useful to me.

Comment: Thanks. For those wondering how to get GPT-4 the answer is to wait... https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4

Comment: I have an account with OpenAI and get access to GPT-4 and all the plugins.  However, using e.g. `LLMEvaluator -> 
 LLMConfiguration[<|"Model" -> "GPT-4", "Temperature" -> 0.9|>]` has no impact. I can use "GPT-4" without any error message but I can also use "GPT-6.5" without any error message.

Comment: @Ernst So you can replicate Stephen’s blog post (up to randomness of reply, of course)? How did you get the GPT-4 API access? (I can only get GPT-4 for the ChatGPT’s web interface.)

Comment: @gwr I actually meant that I can use GPT-4 in ChatGPT’s web interface. As pointed out by others "GPT-4" is listed in the "Advanced Settings" but generates an error message. The option "Model" has no effect. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @gwr I am using the API in Mathematica Online, Mathematica Desktop, CURL, Python, ... ! If you list the available engines  `URLExecute[HTTPRequest["https://api.openai.com/v1/engines", <|
     "Headers" -> {
       "Authorization" -> 
        "Bearer " <> SystemCredential["OPENAI_API_KEY"],
       "Content-Type" -> "application/json"
       }
     |>]];` then "GPT-3.5 ..." pops up in various flavours but "GPT-4" does not.

Comment: @gwr GPT-4 and flavours work since this morning!

Comment: @Ernst Hm, I tried using the "Advanced Settings" in a Chat-Enabled Notebook, but to no avail: "The model 'gpt-4' does not exist or the specified API key does not have access to it." Different for you then?

Answer (score 2):

The upper response is with Setting GPT-4, the lower with GPT-3.5.

[image]